# ParametricPlot not plotting the results I'm getting from NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I try to plot a phase diagram with ParametricPlot but everytime Mathematica does nothing.

I start by ;

```
sol = Solve[{α A k^(α - 1) - ρ - δ == 0,  A k^α - δ k - c == 0}, {c, k}] // FullSimplify


{csol, ksol} = {sol[[1, 1, 2]], sol[[1, 2, 2]]}


Clear[dec, dek, α, A, σ, ρ, δ];

dec = c'[t] == -(c[t]/σ) (A α k[t] ^(α - 1) - δ - ρ);

dek = k'[t] == -(A k[t]^α - c[t] - δ k[t]);

Clear[α, σ, ρ, δ];
α = 0.3; σ = 1; ρ = 0.04; δ = 0.02; A = 1;

Clear[nsba, cb, kb, cf, kf];
nsba = NDSolve[  {dec, dek, c[0] == csol (1 - 10^-5), k[0] == 
                                    ksol (1 - 10^-5)}, {c[t], k[t]}, {t, 0, 255}]

cb[t_] := Evaluate[nsba[[1, 1, 2]]]
kb[t_] := Evaluate[nsba[[1, 2, 2]]]

Clear[tende];
tende = 164;
cf[t_] := cb[tende - t]
kf[t_] := kb[tende - t]
```

After all, I try this last command ;

```
tra = ParametricPlot[{kf[t], cf[t]}, {t, 0, tende},
                     AxesLabel -> {k, c}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]];
```

Mathematica stays actionless. What could be the eventual problem ?

Comment: is the first `Solve[ ]` working for you? What is returning as solutions?

Comment: The semicolon after your plot command suppresses output.

Comment: @belisarius yes the command Solve[ ] works fine. It gives me the right solution for k and c that I have also solved by hand.

Comment: Please post the solutions here. Thanks!

Comment: Optimal, unfortunately very little works in your code. Even trying to understand what you want to do by reading the code is pretty hard. Maybe you could describe the problem you are trying to solve in your question as well. As @belisarius hinted in his comment, the first `Solve` doesn't seem to work for me as written (it throws multiple errors).

Comment: @belisarius thanks for your remark. I will do it.

Comment: @MarcoB you are right but it would have made more dıfficult to read the question if I had wrıtten all stages. Also, personally I think it is always difficult to read someone's code :) Thanks for the comment, I will pay more attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be problems with your use of both `Solve` and `NDSolve`. However, ignoring the warnings *Mathematica* issues and plunging ahead, I get

```
sol = 
  Solve[{α A k^(α - 1) - ρ - δ == 0, A k^α - δ k - c == 0}, {c, k}] // FullSimplify;
{csol, ksol} = {sol[[1, 1, 2]], sol[[1, 2, 2]]};
dec = c'[t] == -(c[t]/σ) (A α k[t]^(α - 1) - δ - ρ);
dek = k'[t] == -(A k[t]^α - c[t] - δ k[t]);
α = 0.3; σ = 1; ρ = 0.04; δ = 0.02; A = 1;
nsba = 
  NDSolve[{dec, dek, c[0] == csol (1 - 10^-5), k[0] == ksol (1 - 10^-5)}, 
    {c[t], k[t]}, {t, 0, 255}];
```

At this point I arrive at the point in the code that is affecting your plot. I fix that by defining

```
cb = Head @ nsba[[1, 1, 2]];
kb = Head @ nsba[[1, 2, 2]];
```

Now

```
With[{tende = 164.},
  With[{cf = cb[tende - #] &, kf = kb[tende - #] &},
    ParametricPlot[{kf[t], cf[t]}, {t, 0, tende},
      AxesLabel -> {k, c},
      AspectRatio -> 1,
      PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]]]
```

produces

[image: plot]

I have no idea whether or not this is a meaningful plot, but at least it shows you what your code is generating.

Comment: Thanks so much, it is very helpful :) I think the problem is possible to be solved analytically.